# attempt to apply non-function

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to build a simple application that draws a histogram of a selected variable based on a subset filtered by the other input. I get the error in the line `hist(dataX()$datasetInput())` which should return `dataX$mpg`. How can I fix it?
Full code:

```
library(shiny)
u <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Staz w bezrobociu"),
  sidebarPanel(

    selectInput("variable", "Variable:",
                list("Milles/gallon",
                     "Horse power")
    ),
    textInput("nc","Number of cylinders",value = 6)
  ),

  mainPanel(
    plotOutput("Plot")
  )

))

s <- shinyServer(function(input, output) 
{
  dataX <- reactive({mtcars[mtcars$cyl==input$nc,,drop = FALSE]})

  datasetInput <- reactive({
    switch(input$variable,
           "Milles/gallon" = mpg,
           "Horse power" = hp)
  })

  output$Plot <- renderPlot({

    hist(dataX()$datasetInput())
  })

})
shinyApp(u,s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You complicated the simple app.

1. You do not need to list all the columns in `selectInput`. You can just render it from the server side.
2. Same applies to the cylinders
3. Shortcuts like `u` and `s`are acceptable, but just stick to the naming conventions. It makes your life easy.

Below is a complete working app

---

```
library(shiny)
ui <- shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Staz w bezrobociu"),
  sidebarPanel(uiOutput("SelectColname"),
               uiOutput("Cylinders")),
  mainPanel(plotOutput("Plot"))
))
```

---

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  # Create a reactive dataset
  dataX <- reactive({
    mtcars
  })

  # Output number cylinders as select box
  output$Cylinders <- renderUI({
    selectInput("cylinders", "cylinders:", unique(dataX()$cyl))
  })

  # Output column names as selectbox
  output$SelectColname <- renderUI({
    selectInput("variable", "Variable:", colnames(dataX()[,c(1,4)]))
  })

  # Based on the selection by user, create an eventreactive plotdata object
  plotdata <- eventReactive(input$cylinders, {
    plotdata = dataX()[dataX()$cyl == input$cylinders, , drop = FALSE]
  })

  # Render the plot, the plot changes when new cylinder is selected
  output$Plot <- renderPlot({
    if (is.null(plotdata()))
      return(NULL)
    hist(
      plotdata()[, input$variable],
      xlab = input$variable,
      main = paste(
        "Histogram of" ,
        input$variable
      )
    )
  })

})
shinyApp(ui, server)
```